# New HP Omen Laptop touchpad disabled when typing, no settings available (Win10)

Tags: windows-10, drivers, windows-registry, touchpad

As per the title I've a new gaming laptop and obviously games tend to need you to use the mouse and keyboard at the same time, I will be getting a proper mouse at some stage but the touchpad is convenient. The model is 15-dh1010na, the touchpad driver is branded Elan or Elantech.

Looking in Device Manager, the input device driver is "ELAN" version 22.2.18.2, last updated 2020/01/13.

There's some other Elan drivers under HIDs, version number same as above:

- Elan HID Class Filter Driver,
- Elan PrecisionTouchpad Filter Driver

There's no option that I can see in Windows 10's questionable settings menus nor under the classic (now "advanced") mouse options. There doesn't seem to be anything in the way of other apps for controlling this. I've seen screenshots from other makes and models that show a specific tab for Elan settings in the mouse options but this is not present on my machine.

I've tried ETDProperties, an app on the Windows Store, which correctly detects the version of the driver but does not list any devices so I can't change any settings.

[Apparently](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Gaming-Notebooks/Omen-Touchpad-Not-Working-When-Typing/td-p/5241776) there used to be an app preinstalled on this brand called Omen Control Center that had a tab with options like these, but this has been replaced with Omen Command Center that doesn't have such options.

There's a myriad of registry entries for Elantech settings (`HKCU/SOFTWARE/Elantech`) but which of these controls this setting, if any, I don't know.

I read on [this post](https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-touchpad-not-working-when-holding-a-keyboard-key/) of a specific reg key "`DisableWhenType_Enable`", but the key is not present for me in the correct location (HKCU/SOFTWARE/Elantech/OtherSettings). I did find it by searching (along with a bunch of other "DisableWhenType_" keys) in some weird location (`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{45672EB9-9059-46A2-838D-4530355F6A77}`). I set this to zero `0` and rebooted but it has not stopped the effect. Secondly I found one in `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\DriverDatabase\DriverPackages\etd.inf_amd64_a449231b0b5ec958\Configurations\ELAN0702_Inst_Win10\Driver\SmartPad` but am told "Cannot edit [...]: Error writing the value's new contents."

Looking further there are actually many instances of the same reg keys, the `ELAN0702` part of the key location changes, iterating from 702 to 072E (Hexadecimal I assume). I've tested a few random instances of the key and cannot change any with the same error.

Finally, there's no touchpad icon like you usually get on laptops in the tray.

Am now clueless, any ideas?

Comment: I suggest not making too many registry changes. If you need HP Support, they may ask you to reinstall your machine.  You might ask them about the touchpad icon in the tray (is there supposed to be one?).  Otherwise the day for a gaming mouse looms earlier than later.

Comment: You might be right. I'm certain it *is* possible to disable this awful setting and I may try just uninstalling the driver and letting the default Windows one run and see if that helps any, though precision might suffer a tad?. Fortunately I should get an offer for a free mouse with this thing in the coming days. No idea if there's meant to be an icon, just mentioned it in case haha, my last laptop is about 7 years old, first time I've had a laptop like this.

Answer (score 0):

**(1) First:** avoid too many registry changes as that makes further changes more difficult.

**(2) Second:** try the Windows Mouse Driver instead of Elantech. Performance should not suffer, but touchpad options will be fewer. You may find a setting you like.

You can always return to the Elantech driver.

> There's no touchpad icon like you usually get on laptops in the tray.

**(3)** That is probably a question for HP. No icon for my Lenovo either. The mouse controls are in Control Panel.

**(4)** Then, hopefully a gaming mouse (free offer or otherwise) is probably the best solution here.

Comment: To my knowledge, this is not a Synaptics device, but Elantech, but yes I'll go ahead and try just using the Windows one. I actually spotted a registry entry for the time in milliseconds that it disables the touchpad so I might make a registry backup and try tweaking that (e.g. setting it zero) hardly ideal though! And yeah registry changes suck, I've only made 1 so far, I'll revert it when I get the chance.

Comment: I changed my answer to Elantech.  My blunder there.

Comment: well, I uninstalled the driver under Mouse in dev manager, nothing changed though I should perhaps have restarted, I also uninstalled the touch driver from under HID and my mouse vanished. lmao. er

Comment: I think you probably need to use the HP Mouse Driver (as they designed it to be mandatory so as to always have a mouse installed).  For your needs, you need an external mouse.

Comment: Sorry I responded a little prematurely, scanning for hardware changes (Alt, A, A) started it working again; though it still has the issue. I've asked on HP's forums though I haven't got a reply yet. If I do ever fix it I'll answer this question! I'll grab an old mouse temporarily for now, it just defeats the point of a laptop being portable haha